# Eclipse Java Doc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I want to automatically generate a template in front of a method like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param tabName
 * @return
 */
```

Web searches have suggested **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** or `/**`. Indeed that has been working for many months. Suddenly today when I do a `/**` it generates only

```
/**
 *
```

oddly enough, more towards the top of the class it works correctly.  Or at least before most classes.

Here is my method def:

```
public String clickIt(Object search, Boolean exact, Object link)
```

but it does not work on other methods either. Any tips on figuring out the problem?

Comment: One control question: have you tried restarting your eclipse/computer (also by computer restart I mean fully turning off and turning on, not just pressing restart option - and yes, there could be a difference)?

Comment: Does you class contain compile errors?  Eclipse cannot build an accurate model if your code is malformed.

Comment: No red rectangles to the right of any code lines, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the template used by Eclipse in the following menu item :
Window > Preferences then Java > Code Style > Code Templates

You can edit the Comments > Methods

The default value is :

```
/**
 * ${tags}
 */
```

Comment: That shows what I would expect:

    /**
     * ${tags}
     */

Sorry.  Those are on separate lines but I can't get this editor to format them.

Comment: Unlucky :)
What happens if you edit this template to add plain text before and after the ${tags} line ?   Something like 
/**   
* BEFORE   
* ${tags}   
* AFTER  
*/

Comment: I will try that.  the /** works fine in other classes.  There must be something strange in this class?

Comment: I have no clue to guess what may be different in this class :)
The other classes you are talking about, are they in the same project, same package ? May you have a character encoding problem ? (mixing utf8, iso8859, windows1252, ......) Did you write this class from scratch, copy/paste from the web, get it from a git/svn repository ?

Comment: Same package, different .java files.  I would say the name of the package but it might be company confidential or something?  And it worked in there before.  I do also believe there is some strange character or something in there, or maybe a comment that comments the end of a method but shows no error?  I did not write this.  Just edited it and added methods and strings.

Comment: Ok, the package name has probably no impact. Did you try to change the file encoding in Eclipse (Edit > Set Encoding...) Or you can also try to copy/paste the content of your file from Eclipse into a simple text editor (as notepad), save it, and copy/paste it again to Eclipse. Maybe........